# Finger print scanner x220 ubuntu 16.04

Tags: fingerprint-reader

I ran this code:
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:fingerprint/fprint
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libfprint0 fprint-demo libpam-fprintd gksu-polkit

Then entered my fingerprint with this:
fprint_demo
It saved. 
Then I ran this line of code:
fprintd-enroll

I then rebooted, it didn't work, still asked for my regular password, I checked the bios, fingerprint scanner enabled. Can any one help me get this working?

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the configuration file at `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` by typing the command `sudo nano /etc/pam.d/common-auth` and adding the line `auth sufficient pam_fprintd.so` above the line that reads `auth [success=1 default=ignore] pam_unix.so nullok_secure try_first_pass`.

Comment: I don't see auth required pam_unix.so, the "required" is missing. This is what I have. Should I add auth sufficient pam_fprint.so  above this: auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure try_first_pass

Comment: Yes, you should add `auth sufficient pam_fprint.so` above the line `auth [success=1 default=ignore] pam_unix.so nullok_secure try_first_pass`.

Comment: Okay, I added that line. I also just restarted and it still won't work. I ran my finger across several times and it doesn't light up or anything

Comment: Try replacing `auth sufficient pam_fprint.so` with `auth sufficient pam_fprintd.so`.

Answer (score 0):

Please use Fingerprint scanner GUI and it works perfectly on my T450 and X220. The ppa is at https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint/+archive/ubuntu/fingerprint-gui